# how to subtract values in a single hashmap while iterating over the map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap containing the food requirement of an individual B for each month as below:

```
Map<String,Float> profileMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Float>();

map.put("B_JAN",8);
map.put("B_FEB",10);
map.put("B_MAR",8);
// ...
```

and so on till DEC

I need to create a new map which will show the consumption for each month. Consumption is calculated by subtracting the current month value from previous month value. So my result should be something like:

{"B_JAN":8,"B_FEB":2,"B_MAR":-2} and so on.

How can I do this calculation while iterating over the map?

Comment: When asking about homework, make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help; your professor is likely to be a better resource at this stage than Stack Overflow.

Comment: How are you iterating over the map? HashMap is not ordered. Why are you not using numbered months instead, say.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `LinkedHashMap` actually maintain the insertion order

Comment: @mikejramsey56 I agree with you.. I had tried a certain implementation but it did not give me the desired result. But i will definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: @SASHA ah good point :D I somehow skipped the `Linked` word

Comment: It would be better to show us what you tried and ask specific questions about that approach.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Open ended questions are more likely to be ignored or even down voted.

Answer (score 1):

The main feature of `LinkedHashMap` over simple `HashMap` is that it maintains the insertion order of keys when you iterate over them. 
Since you're using `LinkedHashMap`, the solution of your problem is pretty straightforward:

```
Map<String,Integer> profileMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

profileMap.put("B_JAN",8);
profileMap.put("B_FEB",10);
profileMap.put("B_MAR",8);

int prev = 0;
Map<String, Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : profileMap.entrySet()) {
    result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() - prev);
    prev = e.getValue();
}

for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : result.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey()+ ": " +e.getValue());
}
```

and the output is, as expected:

```
B_JAN: 8
B_FEB: 2
B_MAR: -2
```

PS: notice that the resulting map can also be of a different type (e.g. `HashMap`) if you don't need keys order anymore. It could also replace values in the `profileMap` map if you don't them anymore.

Comment: You're welcome :) Consider accept the answer if you're fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Map does not keep order of your keys the same as Set doesn't hold the order of its values. There is class SortedMap, but it desn't keep the order of the keys in the order they were added, it sorts them by value. So what you need to do is to keep your keys "B_JAN", "B_FEB" etc in a list in the order that you wish, and then you need to iterate through your list and extract and change values from the map according to your list. It will look something like this:

```
for(int i = 11; i > 0; i--) {
  myMap.put(myList.get(i), myMap.get(myList.get(i)) - myMap.get(myList.get(i-1));
}
```

Comment: LinkedHashMap does keep insertion order, and that's what the OP is using.

Comment: Correct, I overlooked it. Still my answer would work, and if he uses LinkedHashMap he would still need to iterate in reverse order, so as to not to override values which he needs the original value for the next calculation.